# Check if there is a string in the array for login in C

Tags: c

```
// header file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//macros
#define maxchar 9

//part of code
void userLogin() {
    
    static const char pass[] = "12345678";
    char passentry[maxchar],name;
    char user[] = {"user1","user2","user3","user4","user5"};
    int r;

    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t Enter username : ");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        fflush(stdout);

        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t Enter password : ");
        scanf("%s",&passentry);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (strcmp(user[i],name)==0 && strcmp(passentry,pass)==0)
        {
            printf("hello");
        }
        else
        {
            system("CLS");
            sleep(3);
        }
        

    }

}
```

I'm attempting to make the login process check the password and see if the user-entered username is present in the array before granting access to the user's account

Comment: `char user[]` -> `char *user[]` and you should probably put the `fflush(stdout);` before the `scanf`s, not after. There are a bunch of other problems too, like `i`that is not declared and probably othe logic errors etc.

Comment: I see thanks for pointing out the mistakes I made!